# Ext 3: Export large Grid with pagination to Excel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

what is the best practice to export large, paginated grids to XLS in Ext 3.x? I have found [Ext.ux.Exporter](http://edspencer.net/2009/11/ext-ux-exporter-export-any-grid-to-excel-or-csv.html/comment-page-1), but it only exports the grid's current page.

Thanks.

Edit #1:

Thanks everyboy! Stores usually communicate with servers via AJAX and in order to send a download, the request needs to be a normal HTTP-Request. If the best practice to export large grids is serverside - what would be best practice to reroute an extjs store's POST-Request (including all baseParams for filters applied to a grid) away from AJAX, to be able to deliver the serverside-generated xml-export?

Comment: The best way to do it is with a server side technology, like php. You send an ajax request running a script which creates the xls file and downloads it ...

Comment: What are you using on your server-side? I just implemented a CSV export function for my grids in Java, I can share if you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Exporter iterates through records actually in the store. As you said, if the grid is paginated, you will export only records in the active page since is all and only what the store contains.

What do you mean with large? 1000? 1000000 records? In that case I would not recommend to do that on the client.

If you choosed to have pagination, probably you will export to Excel on your server. Some hints: `<html>` table, CSV, PHPExcel.